# How do I use 1 submit button to do 2 actions?

Tags: php, html, forms, mailchimp

I'm trying to submit data to a list in my mail chimp but also allow the user to upload a file.

Here is my code, the first chunk is the mailchimp autogenerated form which is submitted via:

```
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
```

and then it's followed by the basic code to submit a file. But at the moment both functions have a submit button. I want only one. Can anyone help?

```
<body>
    <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
    <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <form action="http://test.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d12b70d4bb1e08c1568d5b392&amp;id=bfb41cbf75" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
            <h2>Subscribe to our test mailing list</h2>
            <div class="indicates-required">
                <span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-EMAIL">
                    Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
                </label>
                <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group">
                <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
                <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
            </div>
            <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
                <strong>Interests </strong>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[5597][1]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-0"><label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-0">Interest 1</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[5597][2]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-1">     <label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-1">Interest 2</label></li>
                    <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[5597][4]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-2"><label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-2">Interest 3</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
            <div class="clear">
                <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
            </div>
        </form>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you mean have one button to upload a file then when the user selects a file the button them triggers the email?

Comment: Maybe a boolean could do the trick?

Comment: @David Jones So the user fills in their details and chooses a file (for instance a CV). The File gets sent to the company and the details are sent into a list in mailchimp - sorry for not explaining well!

Comment: Ok sorry I didnt notice the two submit buttons. So you would only need one submit button to submit all the data, including the upload, to your PHP script then this would process and save the file but also send the email. Could I see the PHP script that handles this form please?

Comment: I haven't created the "upload_file.php" surely that is irrelevant? do I not just need a piece of code that carries out the submit to mailchimp as well as being able to do another action?

Comment: Never place a <form> inside a <form>.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by routing the MailChimp information through your upload_file.php file.

MailChimp has a great API that you can use for more than just adding a subscriber to a list. You would specifically want the [listSubscribe() function](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/rtfm/listsubscribe.func.php). There are some great examples on that page.

Here's more documentation on MailChimp's API: http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/

So in your HTML, you would want to remove the second submit button and make it one form with action="upload_file.php". The PHP file would upload the file, then use the API to submit the data to MailChimp.

You html should look like this:

```
<body>
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
    <form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Subscribe to our test mailing list</h2>
        <div class="indicates-required">
            <span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-EMAIL">
                Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
            </label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group">
            <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
        </div>
        <div class="mc-field-group input-group">
            <strong>Interests </strong>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="group[5597][1]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-0"><label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-0">Interest 1</label></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="group[5597][2]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-1">     <label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-1">Interest 2</label></li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" value="4" name="group[5597][4]" id="mce-group[5597]-5597-2"><label for="mce-group[5597]-5597-2">Interest 3</label></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>

    <div class="clear">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button">
    </div>
</body>
```